# The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)))

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008

Any ideas how to fix this issue.
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))) when you double click a report to open it.
I remember reading on other posts this can occur so the quick and dirty solution is to delete the .suo solution options user file but reopening the report it reappears. If anyone else has a suggestion.
I am guessing the Source Control system I am using might have an effect "Source Tree" but whatever it is it annoying. I know the sometimes the best solution is restart your machine but I am curious to know if there is a known work around.